Shorter and more elegant way to prove that a presheaf is a sheaf?
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a presheaf on a topological space $X$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a base of the topology of $X$. Assume that the presheaf satisfies the following:
For all open $U \subseteq X$ with $U = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ with $U_i \in \mathcal{B}$ and $u_i \in \mathcal{F}(U_i)$ with $u_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} = u_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$ for all $i,j \in I$ there exists a unique $u \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $u|_{U_i} = u_i$.
This implies that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf. One method is to verify this by checking the definition of sheaf. This is a bit annoying since working with double indices and writing out the proof for uniqueness is a bit lengthy (but not difficult) and looks not very nice. Is there a faster, shorter and more elegant way to see this? Maybe by showing that $\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to the sheafification $\mathcal{F}^+$ or using that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf on $\mathcal{B}$ ? It looks like one could write the proof in maybe one line (without missing details).

This seems fairly straightforward. Which part is annoying?

That $F$ is a sheaf on the basis will not be sufficient. We need to talk about covers of arbitrary open subsets with them.

Indeed, F restricts to a sheaf on the basis, which a standard result shows extends uniquely to a sheaf on X. Your condition implies that this is F.

@anon Could you provide a simple proof for this ("Your condition implies that this is F") which satisfies the above requirements? I don't see that it immediately follows.

Below is a proof without any formulas. I have done this just by thinking visually. I hope it helps. If not, please clarify what you are looking for. Then I may adjust the answer accordingly.

For a sheaf we need to verify two things. That sections are uniquely determined by their restrictions along a cover, and that sections glue along a cover. Let us prove uniqueness first.
So assume that we have an open cover of an open subset. We may assume that this open subset is the whole space, just by using the presheaf restricted to the open subset. So we have two global sections that agree on each set of the open cover (blue in the picture). Each of these sets is covered by basis elements (green in the picture). Then the sections agree on all of these basis elements, and they cover the whole space. So by assumption on our presheaf, the two global sections must agree.
Next, assume that we have an open cover of the space and sections on the sets in that cover which are compatible on the intersections. Each set in the cover may be written as a union of basis elements. Let us restrict the sections to these. Then these basis elements cover the space, and we have a section on each of these. Now these are also compatible on the intersections. The reason is that the intersection of two basis elements is contained in the intersection of the corresponding two sets in the original open cover. So by assumption on our presheaf, we get a global section on the whole space that restricts to the local sections on the basis elements. We only need to prove that the global section restricts to the original sections on the open sets in the cover. So let us take one of these open sets. By assumption, the sections agree when restricted to each of the chosen basis elements that cover the open set. So by our assumption on the presheaf, they must be equal.

Yes, this is basically the proof which I meant by checking the definition. I thought that maybe with some more advanced concepts (so not using directly the definition of sheaf) the proof would be about one line. It looks rather similar to sheaf on $\mathcal{B}$ which made me think that there would be a fast way to see that $\mathcal{F}$ is itself the sheaf associated to the sheaf on $\mathcal{B}$. But maybe it is already the "best proof" to verify the definition directly. But the hint of "thinking visually" to see this without formulas was also helpful.

You can probably come up with a proof that uses the fact that limits commute with limits. But I doubt that this is really enlightening.
